# CSS: Scrollable Child Content fails when parent uses max-height instead of height

Tags: html, css

My html structure is as follows:

- main-window (height: 100vh)  // fiddle uses -16px to account for padding on jsfiddle.net

  - workspace (height: 100%)

    - workitem (height: calc(100% - 40px))   // 40px = commands height

      - workitem-hdr (height: 30px)
      - workitem-scrollable (height: calc(100% - 30px))    // 30px = header height
    - commands (height: 40px)

```css
.main-window {
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
}
.workspace {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.workitem {
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
.commands {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.workitem-hdr {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: gray;
}
.workitem-scrollable {
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-window">
  <div class="workspace">
    <div class="workitem">
      <div class="workitem-hdr">
        Item Header
      </div>
      <div class="workitem-scrollable">
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
      </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="commands">
      <button>Save</button>
      <button>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See working fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/d4msvep2/

All is good.  When I reduce height of window I get the scrollable content as required.

### Challenge

The problem with this is that commands are at the bottom of the screen (potentially a long way from where the action is).  What I'd like to achieve is that the commands appear just below the workitem.  So, I changed workitem to:

```
max-height: calc(100% - 40px);
```

```css
.main-window {
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
}
.workspace {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.workitem {
  max-height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
.commands {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.workitem-hdr {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: gray;
}
.workitem-scrollable {
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-window">
  <div class="workspace">
    <div class="workitem">
      <div class="workitem-hdr">
        Item Header
      </div>
      <div class="workitem-scrollable">
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
      </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="commands">
      <button>Save</button>
      <button>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that this now breaks my workitem-scrollable

Broken fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/zo2rcahm/

How might I get the button close to where the work is happening, rather than at the bottom of the screen, but also maintain the scrollable workitem-scrollable?

Answer (score 1):

`.workitem-scrollable` has a `max-height: calc(100% - 40px)`

The value `100%` for height is based on a fixed height of the parent element. But the parent element `.workitem` has only `max-height`, - which is no gien fix height.

So `workitem-scrollable`takes so much height as it needs/wants. If you advice a fix height to `.workitem`(i.e. 200px) it imidiatly is scrollable ... ;-)

So: just advice the property `height` with the value you need to `.workitem` and you can go on ...

```css
.main-window {
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
}
.workspace {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.workitem {
  max-height: calc(100% - 40px);
  /* ADDED */
  height: 200px;
}
.commands {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.workitem-hdr {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: gray;
}
.workitem-scrollable {
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-window">
  <div class="workspace">
    <div class="workitem">
      <div class="workitem-hdr">
        Item Header
      </div>
      <div class="workitem-scrollable">
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
        <div>row</div>
      </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="commands">
      <button>Save</button>
      <button>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Brebber, but in this scenario, I do not have a fixed height at any point in the hierarchy.  It is all based on the viewport height and everything should adjust from there.  Using a `calc`'d height is fine, but using a `calc`'d max-height is where it falls over.

Comment: May be ... but if you whant to make an element scrollable you need to give the element a fix height. And to do that WITH a percentage based value (i.e. 100%) that ONLY works if the parent element has a fixed height ... that's the general mechanic you have to use in css. But thinking forward: using viewport height makes it possible to advise the elements a fix height, i.e. `height: 80vH`... most often that's just a question of calculation ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I think the "fixed" height is not so relevant.  My working fiddle does not have any fixed heights.  The issue is all around the introduction of max-height instead of height (because I want the control to be smaller if it can be).  Hmmm.